# How to handle multiple requests through an Ajax API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a large project that requires multiple functions to be processed through Ajax calls, so far I am using different files to handle each function call. I know there's got to be a better way to handle the requests through an API

And what would be a standard practice for designing such an API in terms of structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Best-practice questions tend to be broad, and trigger knee-jerk close votes as a result. I recommend avoiding them here.

Comment: @BoltClock - That fell on deaf ears ?

Comment: @adeneo: I meant avoiding best-practice questions, not avoiding the votes. I guess the OP hasn't chosen to edit it out, so that would be falling on deaf ears too.

Comment: I'm expecting a broad answer. Still I changed the best practice line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be everything from something quite simple, to something more complicated, how you write it is up to you, assuming you're the only one who's going to use the API, and as far as I know there are no standards set in stone for this kind of thing, but a good way to solve things like this is to create a convenience function, both clientside and serverside, say something like

```
function fetch(what, data) {
    data.what = what;

    return $.ajax({
        url      : '/my/ajaxapi.php',
        data     : data,
        dataType : 'json'
    });
}
```

And when you need something you do

```
fetch('users', {name : 'Bill'}).done(function(result) {
    $('#user').text(result.text);
});

$('.zoidberg').on('click', function() {
    var self = this;

    fetch('zoidberg', {}).done(function(result) {
        $(self).text(result.text);
    });
});
```

on the serverside you have one file, and how you set it up depends on the language used, but say PHP, and you could of course get fancy with classes etc. or just do a simple if/else or switch/case

```
<?php

    $key = $_GET['what']; // wrap in something that makes it safe
    $res = Array();

    switch($key) {
        case 'users' : 
           // lookup in DB or something
           $res['text'] = $username;
        break;
        case 'zoidberg' :
           $res['text'] = " Why Must I Be a Crustacean in Love";
    }

    echo json_encode($res);

?>
```

It's just a quick example, but set it up so it fits what you're doing, and it can save you a lot of work, and you have everything in one place so it's easy to find and modify later, easy to add new things that can be gotten with ajax etc. and possibly only need to get resources, DB connection etc. once, and not in every file.

Comment: Very good example. I usually do the `fetch()` function to pass through the callback and access it like that (`fetch(url, data, function(response)) {...`) but this is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you can do -

Instead of creating multiple files to process AJAX request, just make a single file and then create different functions for different types of operations.

Specify in your AJAX request to which function you want to call and then run only that function.

By this, way you don't have to manage multiple files for different types of operations.

e.g.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type     : "POST",
        url      : 'myfile.php',
        data     : {'action': 'func1_name', 'val': 'some_value'} //wants to call a specific function 
    },
success:function(response){
console.log(response);
}
);
```

PHP:

```
//executing func1
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'func1_name'){
    func1();
}

function func1(){
   if(isset($_POST['val']))
   echo $_POST['val'];
   die();
}

function func2(){

}
```